# How to solve "(TInput input)" syntax errors ？

Tags: c#

I read a code to realize queue type conversion, and the character < >, I don't quite understand what function this character realizes here。
Here **FileIOXml.<>c.<>9.a **Unable to understand what functionality 'FileIOXml.<>c.<>9.a' implements。Syntax error during copying and recompiling
Class "FileIOXml" have method name "c" and "a", Method "a" has multiple overloads.

```
string innerText9 = string.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll<Color, string>((Color[])a_.Value, new Converter<Color, string>(FileIOXml.<>c.<>9.a)));
```

Comment: _"FileIOXml.<>c.<>9.a"_ It looks something generated or bad presentation of a class, it isn't valid syntax IMHO. Maybe if you add some more details, we might see why this occurs.

Comment: This looks like code produced by a decompiler that didn't quite understand what the compiler and/or obfuscator produced. Both the C# compiler and obfuscators will use characters in identifiers that are legal in intermediate language, but not legal in C#. You are never supposed to see or use such names directly. If you are using third-party tools, you'll have to specify which ones.

Comment: Yes, this is the code read by decompilation. I've noticed that "Array. Convertall" is used here to convert "Color[] "to "string". So can I understand "new Converter<Color, string>(FileIOXml.<>c.<>9.a)" as "Defines a method called 'FileIOXml.<>c.<>9' that converts a Color type  to string type". As you said, don't just use "FileIOXml.<>c.<>9" and rename it "ColorTostring“.                                                                                
  public static string ColorToString(Color A_0)   
   {   
       return ;   
   }

Comment: private  static string ColorTostring(Color A_0)
        {
            string text = A_0.Name;

            return text;
        }